# How to stop opening files in browser upon save

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2 (which I love). I have it set to auto-save upon lost focus, to it automatically saves.  Somehow, however, I've done something such that when it saves, it opens in a browser. This must be some build function that's getting triggered, but I don't know where to look for it.  I looked for a BuildOnSave package in the installed packages, but I didn't see anything remotely related to 'Save' or 'Build', etc.

Does anyone have any ideas of where to look?  I don't really want to have to revert to pristine state and then have to re-install my plugins as this us pretty darn annoying.

My currently installed packages are below, if it helps.

```
"installed_packages":
[
    "AMD Module Editor",
    "CoffeeScript",
    "Dayle Rees Color Schemes",
    "Emmet",
    "Emmet Css Snippets",
    "Git",
    "Gitignore",
    "JSLint",
    "LESS",
    "Markdown Preview",
    "Package Control",
    "SublimeLinter"
],
```

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling `Markdown Preview`, as it looks like it could be the culprit. It has some built-in build systems, and you likely somehow activated a "build on save" feature. None of the other packages (that I'm aware of) have similar functionality that would give the symptoms you're seeing.

To deactivate, select `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` to open a file browser window of the Sublime Text 2 `Packages` directory. Move (don't copy) the `Packages/Markdown Preview` directory to someplace else, like your Desktop, for now. Quit and restart ST2, and see if the issue persists. If not, this plugin was at fault, and you can start poking around in its settings (after moving it back to the `Packages` folder) to see where the error is. One place to look is in `Tools -> Build System` and deselect `Markdown`.

Good luck!

Comment: So, I quit ST2.  Move the Markdown Preview folder to desktop.  Restart ST2 and the friggin' folder returns.  Should I uninstall the package instead of merely moving it?

Comment: I uninstalled it and while it did not come back ;^) it did not fix the issue.  What fixed it was that under Tools, Build System... I have a custom build profile called Chrome that was selected.  I changed it back to Automatic and it's working the way I wanted it to.  Thanks.

Comment: @Scott - I forgot about the "auto-reinstall" feature of Package Control - if a package is missing upon restart, it gets automatically installed again unless you remove it from your `Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings` file.

Comment: I'm glad you were finally able to track down the problem. If you feel my answer was helpful in any way, feel free to upvote it and/or select it as answered, even if I missed the exact reason for the issue, hopefully I put you on the right track :)